# Deriving posterior pdf in classical linear normal regression model under noninformative prior

Tags: self-study, bayesian

Question: Assume the following classical linear normal regression model:
\begin{gather*}
y_{i} = \beta_1 x_{1i} + \beta_2 x_{2i} + \cdots + \beta_K x_{Ki} + e_i \\
\underbrace{\boldsymbol{y}}_{n \times 1} = \underbrace{\boldsymbol{X}}_{n \times K}\underbrace{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_{K \times 1} + \underbrace{\boldsymbol{e}}_{n \times 1}
\end{gather*}

where $e_i \sim iid \ N(0, \sigma^2)$ for $i = 1, 2, \cdots, n$ and $x_{1i} = 1$ for $i = 1, 2, \cdots, n$

Define $\boldsymbol{\beta} = (\beta_1, \beta_2, \cdots, \beta_K)'$ and assume a noninformative prior of the form $p(\boldsymbol{\beta}, \sigma) \propto \frac{1}{\sigma}$, derive the conditional posterior pdfs for $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ and $\sigma$, that is, $p(\boldsymbol{\beta}|\sigma, \mathbf{y})$ and $p(\sigma|\boldsymbol{\beta}, \mathbf{y})$.

---

I can derive the conditional posterior pdf for $p(\boldsymbol{\beta}|\sigma, \mathbf{y})$  but I am not sure how to derive it for $p(\sigma|\boldsymbol{\beta}, \mathbf{y})$. The answer to the latter is:

$p(\sigma|\boldsymbol{\beta}, \mathbf{y})=\frac{2}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}\left(\frac{na}{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}} \frac{1}{\sigma^{n+1}}\exp\left[-\frac{na}{2\sigma^2}\right] $

where $a = \frac{1}{n}\left(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}\right)'\left(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}\right)$

---

The following is my working to derive the posterior pdf for $p(\boldsymbol{\beta}|\sigma, \mathbf{y})$

We have:
\begin{align*}
p(\boldsymbol{e}|\sigma) & = \prod_{i=1}^n p(e_i) \\
& = \prod_{i=1}^n (2\pi \sigma^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}e_i^2\right] \\
& = (2\pi \sigma^2)^{-\frac{n}{2}}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n e_i^2\right] \\
& = (2\pi \sigma^2)^{-\frac{n}{2}} \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \boldsymbol{e'}\boldsymbol{e}\right] 
\end{align*}
Since $p(\boldsymbol{y}) = p(\boldsymbol{e})\left|\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{e'}}{\partial \boldsymbol{y}} \right|$ and $\boldsymbol{y} = \boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{e} \Longleftrightarrow \boldsymbol{e} = \boldsymbol{y} - \boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}$, then $\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{e'}}{\partial \boldsymbol{y}}  = \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{y'}}{\partial \boldsymbol{y}} = \boldsymbol{I}_{n}$. Hence, $\left|\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{e'}}{\partial \boldsymbol{y}} \right| = \left| \boldsymbol{I}_{n}\right| = 1$. So:
\begin{align*}
p(\boldsymbol{y}|\boldsymbol{\beta}, \sigma) & = p(\boldsymbol{e}) \\
& = (2\pi \sigma^2)^{-\frac{n}{2}} \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\left(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}\right)'\left(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}\right)\right] \ \ \text{since} \ \ \boldsymbol{e} = \boldsymbol{y} - \boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} 
\end{align*}
Thus we have:
$$L(\boldsymbol{\beta}, \sigma|\boldsymbol{y}) \propto (\sigma^2)^{-\frac{n}{2}} \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\left(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}\right)'\left(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}\right)\right]$$
Given $p(\boldsymbol{\beta}, \sigma) \propto \frac{1}{\sigma}$, we have:
\begin{align*}
p(\boldsymbol{\beta}, \sigma|\boldsymbol{y}) & \propto L(\boldsymbol{\beta}, \sigma|\boldsymbol{y}) \times p(\boldsymbol{\beta}, \sigma) \\ 
& \propto \frac{1}{\sigma^n}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\left(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}\right)'\left(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}\right)\right] \times \frac{1}{\sigma} \\
& = \frac{1}{\sigma^{n+1}} \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\left[(n-K)\widehat{\sigma}^2 + (\boldsymbol{\beta} - \boldsymbol{b})'\boldsymbol{X}'\boldsymbol{X}(\boldsymbol{\beta}-\boldsymbol{b})\right] \right\} \\
& \text{where} \ \ \widehat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n-K} (\boldsymbol{y} - \boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{b})'(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{b}) \ \ \text{and} \ \ \boldsymbol{b} = (\boldsymbol{X}'\boldsymbol{X})^{-1}\boldsymbol{X}'\boldsymbol{y} \\
& = \underbrace{\frac{1}{\sigma^K} \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(\boldsymbol{\beta} - \boldsymbol{b})'\boldsymbol{X}'\boldsymbol{X}(\boldsymbol{\beta}-\boldsymbol{b})\right]}_{f^n(\boldsymbol{\beta}|\sigma, \boldsymbol{y})} \underbrace{\frac{1}{\sigma^{n-K+1}} \exp\left[-\frac{(n-K)\widehat{\sigma}^2}{2\sigma^2}\right]}_{f^n(\sigma|\mathbf{y})}
\end{align*}
Note that $f^n(\boldsymbol{\beta}|\sigma, \boldsymbol{y})$ is a kernel for $\boldsymbol{\beta}$, where $\boldsymbol{\beta} \sim MVN(\boldsymbol{b}, \sigma^2(\boldsymbol{X}'\boldsymbol{X})^{-1})$ and $f^n(\sigma|\mathbf{y})$ is a kernel for $\sigma$ where $\sigma \sim IG(v, \widehat{\sigma})$ and $v = n-K$, $\widehat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{v} \left(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}\right)'\left(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}\right)$. Thus we have:
$$p(\boldsymbol{\beta}, \sigma|\mathbf{y}) = p(\boldsymbol{\beta}|\sigma, \boldsymbol{y})p(\sigma|\mathbf{y})$$
where:
\begin{gather*}
p(\boldsymbol{\beta}|\sigma, \boldsymbol{y}) = (2\pi)^{-\frac{K}{2}}|\sigma^2(\boldsymbol{X}'\boldsymbol{X})^{-1}|^{-\frac{1}{2}}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(\boldsymbol{\beta} - \boldsymbol{b})'\boldsymbol{X}'\boldsymbol{X}(\boldsymbol{\beta}-\boldsymbol{b})\right] \\
p(\sigma|\mathbf{y}) = \frac{2}{\Gamma\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)} \left(\frac{v\widehat{\sigma}^2}{2}\right)^{\frac{v}{2}}\frac{1}{\sigma^{v+1}}\exp\left[-\frac{v\widehat{\sigma}^2}{2\sigma^2}\right]
\end{gather*}

Comment: I answered this question in my previous answer to your question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68424/gibbs-sampling-to-produce-posterior-pdf by using the decomposition $$p(\beta,\sigma^2|y,X)=p(\beta|\sigma^2,y,X)p(\sigma^2|y,X)$$.

Comment: @BakakP Thanks for your indepth post in the other thread, however here I am wondering how you can derive the conditional distribution of $p(\sigma|\boldsymbol{\beta}, \mathbf{y})$. Similar to your other post, we both arrived at the same posterior pdf for $\sigma|\mathbf{y}$, but how do you derive the conditional pdf for $\sigma|\boldsymbol{\beta}, \mathbf{y}$?

Comment: I don't derive $\sigma|\beta,y$

Comment: Once you have obtained $\beta,\sigma|y$ the easy thing to do is to integrate out $\beta$ to obtain $\sigma|y$, i.e., $$p(\sigma|y)=\int_{R^p}p(\beta,\sigma|y)d\beta$$

Comment: @BakakP Yes I understand, however this is a separate question that I'm wondering. How do we derive the distribution of $\sigma|\beta, \mathbf{y}$? I have no idea...

Comment: In my bayesian statistics class, I've been taught to approach the problem by decomposition (as you've mentioned in the other thread), so in my above post, to derive the distribution of $p(\beta|\sigma, \mathbf{y})$, I used the decomposition $p(\beta, \sigma|\mathbf{y}) = p(\beta|\sigma, \mathbf{y})p(\sigma|\mathbf{y})$, now to derive the distribution of $p(\sigma|\beta, \mathbf{y})$ I suspect we should decompose as $p(\beta, \sigma|\mathbf{y}) = p(\sigma|\beta, \mathbf{y})p(\beta|\mathbf{y})$, but I am unsure of how to proceed down that route...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the following posterior distribution

$$p(\beta,\sigma^2|y)\propto L(\beta,\sigma^2|y)\times p(\beta,\sigma^2)$$
and so, the full conditional $\sigma^2,\beta,y$ can be derived as the following:

\begin{align*}
p(\sigma^2|\beta,y)&\propto\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\right)^{n/2}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(y-X\beta)'(y-X\beta)\right\}\times\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\\
&\propto\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\right)^{n/2+1}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\left[(\beta-\hat\beta)'(X'X)(\beta-\hat\beta)+(n-k)\hat\sigma^2\right]\right\}\\
&\propto\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\right)^{n/2+1}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(\beta-\hat\beta)'(X'X)(\beta-\hat\beta)\right\}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(n-k)\hat\sigma^2\right\}\\
&\propto\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\right)^{n/2+1}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(n-k)\hat\sigma^2\right\}\\
&\propto(\sigma^2)^{-(n/2+1)}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\frac{(n-k)\hat\sigma^2}{2}\right\}
\end{align*}

And so $$\sigma|\beta,y \sim\text{Inverse-Gamma}\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{(n-k)\hat\sigma^2}{2}\right)$$
Double check that my arithmetic is all fine but that is how you would derive it.

Comment: I leave out the algebra between the first two lines of derivations but that is just decomposing the likelihood using the sufficient statistics.

Comment: @BakakP Great, I understand all of that, however the only thing I am unclear about is this the statement: $p(\sigma^2|\beta,y)\propto\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\right)^{n/2}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} (y-X\beta)'(y-X\beta)\right\}\times\frac{1}{\sigma^2}$ ...(1). I know that $L(\beta,\sigma^2|y) \propto \left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\right)^{n/2}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(y-X\beta)'(y-X\beta)\right\}$ and the noninformative prior is given by $p(\beta,\sigma^2) \propto \frac{1}{\sigma^2}$

Comment: (cont...), but shouldn't the LHS of (1) be $p(\sigma^2, \beta|y)$ rather than $p(\sigma^2|\beta,y)$ since $p(\beta,\sigma^2|y)\propto L(\beta,\sigma^2|y)\times p(\beta,\sigma^2)$?

Comment: It's the standard way to find a full conditional.  You set the full conditional that you want (in your case $p(\sigma^2|\beta,y)$) equal to the full posterior and you start dropping terms where ever you can based on what you conditioned on.

Comment: What exactly is meant by "full conditional?"

Comment: For each parameter, the full conditional
distribution is the distribution of the parameter conditional on the known information and all the other parameters: $p(\theta_j|\theta_{-j},y)$.  Read the wikipedia page on Gibbs sampling and they will talk about it some more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_sampling

Comment: @BakakP Ahh I understand! So it's like saying... $p(\sigma | \beta, y) = \frac{p(\beta, \sigma^2|y)}{p(\beta|y)} \propto p(\beta, \sigma^2|y) \propto L(\beta,\sigma^2|y)\times p(\beta,\sigma^2) $ and the rest follows from your working

Comment: Exactly.  I guess I should have showed that step.

Comment: @BakakP Looks like I can sleep in peace tonight :) Thank you again for your help in this thread and the other one, looking forward to learning more from you in the future :)